# Como añadir roles en un $_SESSION

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, base-de-datos

estoy haciendo una página de juegos y me gustaría que algunos juegos solo pudieran acceder los usuarios premium. Tengo una tabla en la bd usuarios con una columna "premium" si/no y quisiera saber como hacer para que algunos juegos solo aparecieran si te logueas con un usuario premium.

server.php

```
if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);

if (empty($username)) {
    array_push($errors, "Se requereix nombre de usuari");
}
if (empty($password)) {
    array_push($errors, "Se requereix contrasenya");
}

// Quan et loguejes sense errors
if (count($errors) == 0) {
    $password = md5($password);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
    $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['success'] = "Ara estàs conectat";
        header('location: ../index.php');
    }
    else {
        array_push($errors, "Combinació usuari/contrasenya malament");
    }
}
```

index.php

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="main">
        <a name="jocs">
            <table class="table_jocs">
                <tr align="center">
                    <td><h2>Typer</h2></td>
                    <td><h2>Brainer</h2></td>
                    <td><h2>PPT</h2></td>
                    <td><h2>Draw me!</h2></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="/typer" target="_blank"><img src="/imagens/mecanografia.png" class="iconos_jocs"></a></td>
                    <td><a href="/brainer" target="_blank"><img src="/imagens/brainer.png" class="iconos_jocs"></a></td>
                    <td><a href="/pedra_paper_tisores" target="_blank"><img src="/imagens/ppt.png" class="iconos_jocs"></a></td>
                    <td><a href="/draw" target="_blank"><img src="/imagens/dibuix.png" class="iconos_jocs"></a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr align="center">
                    <td><h2>Velocity</h3></td>
                    <td><h2>Were's Wally?</h2></td>
                    <td><h2>Bowser Game</h2></td>
                    <td><h2>Moveless</h2></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <?php if (($_SESSION['premium']) == 'si') { ?>
                        <td><a href="/velocity" target="_blank"><img src="/imagens/velocity.png" class="iconos_jocs"></a></td>
                        <td><a href="/wally" target="_blank"><img src="/imagens/wally.png" class="iconos_jocs"></a></td>
                        <td><a href="/bowser" target="_blank"><img src="/imagens/bowser.png" class="iconos_jocs"></a></td>
                        <td><a href="/moveless" target="_blank"><img src="/imagens/ma.svg" class="iconos_jocs"></a></td>
                    <?php } ?>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Que tipo de datos guarda la columna premium?

Comment: varchar de 2 carácteres (si y no)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A la hora de comprobar el usuario y contraseña, puedes pones una comprobación de que el usuario y la contraseña existe ademas de si es premium. Despues guardarlo en la variable `$_SESSION['premium']`.

```
if (count($errors) == 0) 
{
    $password = md5($password);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
    $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    $fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resuls) //Variable $fila
    if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1)
    {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['success'] = "Ara estàs conectat";
        header('location: ../index.php');
    }
    else if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1 && $fila['premium'] == "si")
    {
        $_SESSION['premium'] = "si";//Variable para saber si el usuario es premium
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['success'] = "Ara estàs connectat usuari premium";
        header('location: ../index.php'); //Debería ir tu pagina de juegos creo
    }
    else 
    {
        array_push($errors, "Combinació usuari/contrasenya malament");
    }
}
```

Comment: la $fila la tengo que declarar? dónde? cómo?

Comment: Perdona se me olvidó ponerlo, ahora edito la respuesta.

Comment: Vale gracias ahora lo pruebo, imagino que sera *results i ; no? "$fila = mysqli_fetch_array($results);"

Comment: Ya he editado la respuesta, a ver si te funciona.

Comment: no, parece que no me funciona :((

Comment: como asignas el si/no a tus usuarios para ser premium?

Comment: $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password, rol, premium) VALUES('$username', '$email', '$password', 'normal', 'no')";
y si quiero que alguien sea premium lo cambio en la bd directamente

Comment: tienes algún usuario que tenga el campo premium con 'si'? El campo rol que guarda a parte de 'normal'?

Comment: si, hay 2 que es "si". A parte de normal está admin (es para el blog para que puedas borrar y editar comentarios desde la página)

Comment: aquí una foto con mi tabla https://gyazo.com/b98ae2468d06db5e2e53d962da3bc57f

Comment: Te sale algún error? Cuando te logueas con usuario 'premium' que es lo que te muestra?

Comment: no me salen los juegos, me sale lo mismo que si me logueo con un usuario no premium. no me sale ningún error

Comment: En el `else if` que te puse, en el header, tienes puesto index.php, quizás debas poner la dirección a la página de juegos

Comment: si, era eso, MUCHAS GRACIAS!

Answer (score 0):

Añadiendo el valor de la columna premium a la superglobal $_SESSION deberia funcionarte.
Ejemlo:

```
if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);

if (empty($username)) {
    array_push($errors, "Se requereix nombre de usuari");
}
if (empty($password)) {
    array_push($errors, "Se requereix contrasenya");
}

// Quan et loguejes sense errors
if (count($errors) == 0) {
    $password = md5($password);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
    $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
        $fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)//Debes obtener el resultado
        $_SESSION['username'] = $fila['username'];
        $_SESSION['premium'] =  $fila['premium'];//Obtienes el valor de 
                                                    //la columna premium
        $_SESSION['success'] = "Ara estàs conectat";
        header('location: ../index.php');
    }
    else {
        array_push($errors, "Combinació usuari/contrasenya malament");
    }
}
```

Tras hacer eso la página HTML deberia de funcionarte bien y mostrar o no, según el rol en base de datos.